# How to Enable Scrolling for Overflowing Content in a CSS Grid Layout?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

Hello StackOverflow Community,
I'm currently working on a HTML/CSS project where I have a 3 column grid layout. The left column contains a terminal-like interface with an output area and an input area. The output area () contains paragraphs of text that often exceed the available vertical space.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>WebSocket Game Client</title>

</head>

<style>
  html,
  body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .three-columns {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  }
  
  .split {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .horizontal-gutter {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: black;
  }
  
  .terminal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
    background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
    font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
    font-size: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .output-buffer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .input-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    background-color: rgb(69, 64, 64);
    padding: 5px;
  }
  
  .command-input {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(69, 64, 64);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="main" class="three-columns">
    <div id="split-1" class="split">
      <div class="terminal">
        <div id="output" class="output-buffer">
          <p>This is an output buffer that is expected to have scrollbars on this div when the content exceeds its size. Instead it expands. </p>
          <!-- Repeated content will be generated here by JavaScript -->
        </div>
        <div id="input" class="input-wrapper">
          <input id="command-input" type="text" placeholder="> command" autocomplete="off" class="command-input" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal-gutter"></div>
    <div id="split-2" class="split">
      <div style="background-color: rgb(72, 0, 0); height: 100%; width: 100%;" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    // Get the output buffer element
    var outputBuffer = document.getElementById('output');

    // Generate many paragraphs of psuedo-content
    // to overflow the output buffer and show the problem
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.textContent = 'All your base are belong to us!';
      outputBuffer.appendChild(p);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

My intention is for the output-buffer div to have appropriate scrollbars when the content doesn't fit. However, instead of showing a scrollbar, the div just expands its size to accommodate the extra content.

I've tried using overflow: auto; and height: 100%; on the output-buffer, but it doesn't work as expected. Instead of the div becoming scrollable, it just expands its size. At least in the vertical as (sometimes, depending on different approaches) too-wide content does provide a horizontal scrollbar as expected (shrink browser window width to see this).

How can I modify my CSS so that the output-buffer becomes scrollable when the content overflows, and doesn't expand its size?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You said that you tried to set `height: 100%` on `.output-buffer`. `100%` of *what*? All its ancestors, from `.terminal` to `html`, have `height: 100%`. `100%` of `100%` of nothing is nothing, which CSS can't comprehend. It surrenders and uses `.output-buffer`'s normal height instead.

Comment: True, 100% all the way to the top (err.. bottom?) is 100% of nothing.  But I also tried 100vh at html, body, .three-columns to no effect.  I presume that 100% of that is valid.  The crazier part to me is a horizontal scroll bar does appear, just not the vertical.  So it "half works".  Sample in Question updated to use 100vh to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that Grid layout has an odd behavior when it comes to nested divs and overflow. This might be by design or a gray area in terms of implementation in browsers.  I can find no spec that suggests this is correct so far.

The achieve the proper behavior, use flex layout instead. This seems to respect overflow of inner divs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using overflow-y: auto; is the right thing to do to add scrolling, now you just need to set a max-height. Right now it can't add scrolling when the div gets too big, because it doesn't know what "too big" is.
Try something like-

```
.output-buffer {
  max-height: 400px; /* change this to whatever height you want */
}
```

Edit: If it has to be dynamically sized, try view height instead of pixels, like this-

```
  .output-buffer {
    max-height: 95vh; /* adjust this as needed */
  }
```

Comment: The max-height can't be specified in pixels, for it needs to be 100% of its container (at least in my use-case).   Setting height and max-height on .output-buffer to 100% doesn't seem to have any impact.

Comment: @DavidWhatley I edited my answer. I hope it helps!

Comment: The ultimate use of this will be in a dynamic layout where  it must constrain itself to its parent div's size.  This won't be the viewport, unfortunately.  It kind of is in the example, but that's not how it'll ultimately be used:  Think of a user dynamically splitting the view horizontally and/or vertically at will (and recursively at that).

Comment: @DavidWhatley the problem with that is that your parent component (.terminal) doesn't have a max-height. It is currently 100% of nothing specific. If you can set .terminal {max-height: 100vh;} then that should solve the problem as well. It has to be based on something with a max-height or it will continue to grow. The output buffer isn't bigger than the terminal right now, the terminal is growing to fit the content. I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: I cannot do that because the terminal has to be constrained by its parents size.  In this example that might work, but the way the app that this is intended for functions, the terminal can be in any sized cell of a grid and has to constrain to it.

Comment: @DavidWhatley If the example has a different solution than your actual code, maybe you should update it to include the full problem. Otherwise, the problem has been solved based on the code you provided. It sounds like you're saying the terminal *will* have a max height based on *something*, so you should be able to use max-height on that and the output buffer, whether you use percentages or another metric. The point is that they both need a max-height (whether explicit or implicit) if you want the output buffer to scroll... if they don't then they will just keep growing.

Comment: The example is purposeful simplification, and as written demonstrates the problem.

Attempts to fix it with height and max-height changes do not solve the issue (assuming the use-case is not violated).

Near as I can tell it is a problem in grid layout, based on further experimentation.  Maybe even a bug, I can't find a spec that says this is proper behavior.

Flex seems to work more like I expect, so trying that now.